# php i have a comment system move comments closer

Tags: php, html, comments, echo, move

i have a website where you display your twitter link and people can follow u and what not i wwould like the posts to be move closer together as you can see their too far apart this is the website http://twitterdistrict.comuf.com/index.php

the comment code is this

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
     $id=$rows['id'];
     $dname=$rows['name'];
     $dcomment=$rows['comment'];

     echo '<div id="username_word"><font color="red">username:</font></div>' ."<a href='$dname' id = 'name' style='color: #77cde6' STYLE='TEXT-DECORATION: NONE'>$dname</a>"."<div id ='dash'><font color='red'> - </font> </div>"."<div id='comment'>$dcomment</div>" 
  ."<div id='followbtn'><a href='$dname'><img src='http://i45.tinypic.com/2yltzkg.png' width ='30px' height ='30px' border='0' alt='follow'></div></a>" ;    

     }
?>
```

Comment: You would think it would be close enough, without all that interpunction inbetween.

Comment: Interpuction. Not heard that one for a while :)

Comment: Sorry, what is it called nowadays? Punctuation?

Comment: Absolutely no idea at all. I don't think anybody else knows either on account of the vast lack of information given by you.

Comment: sorry im new to this site should i post the entire website code?

Comment: _Should i post the entire website code?_ - please don't do that `:)`. I'd recommend converting your `<font>` and `style` information to a separate CSS file, so you can just add a single class to your div. Much easier to adjust, and much easier to read!

Comment: Also, try validating the page at W3C. You have several non-unique `id`s, which is a problem (though not in itself responsible for the formatting, it is excellent to fix this).

Comment: would this help with removing the spaces? thank you for the reply

Comment: thank you so much ile try it and get back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that code:

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
     $id=$rows['id'];
     $dname=$rows['name'];
     $dcomment=$rows['comment'];
?>
<div id="username_word"><font color="red">username:</font></div><a href="<?php echo $dname; ?>" id="name" style="color: #77cde6" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE"><?php echo $dname; ?></a><div id="dash"><font color="red"> - </font> </div><div id="comment"><?php echo $dcomment; ?></div><div id="followbtn"><a href="<?php echo $dname; ?>"><img src="http://i45.tinypic.com/2yltzkg.png" width ="30px" height ="30px" border="0" alt="follow"></div></a>
<?php
 }
?>
```

I replaced the echo by simple HTML. The values are inserted into the HTML by using `echo` within the HTML code.